# node.js heroku - "error Failed at the ws@0.4.8 preinstall script"

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I am following the steps listed at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs for deploying my app on heroku

I get the following error message while deploying

```
854 info build /tmp/build_4cdbd3fc-aa32-4d15-9366 ebdef5c5cb93/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
855 info preinstall ws@0.4.8
856 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
857 info ws@0.4.8 Failed to exec preinstall script
858 error ws@0.4.8 preinstall: `make`
858 error Exit status 2
859 error Failed at the ws@0.4.8 preinstall script.
859 error This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
859 error not with npm itself.
859 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
859 error     make
859 error You can get their info via:
859 error     npm owner ls ws
```

I see similar questions here but none of the solutions work for me since I am deploying on heroku (guessing?).

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Upgraded Web Sockets to the latest stable version!